# Cannot understand SDK documentation for a RFID desktop reader

Tags: java, android, rfid

I am working with a RFID device which is completely unmarked and the sdk was sent seperately with no make and model and no sdk online.

I am trying to set the device power to max and get the power of the reader.

According to the docs :

The code for setting power :

```
  public String SetPower(AsyncSocketState state, byte readpower, byte writepower) {
        byte type = 0;
        byte[] msgbody = new byte[]{0, readpower, writepower};
        byte[] command = this.cmd.PackSelector(msgbody, type);
        return !this.Send(state, command) ? "-4" : "0";
    }
```

For getting power:

```
   public String GetPower(AsyncSocketState state) {
        Respond.Power = "";
        byte type = 12;
        byte[] msgbody = new byte[0];
        byte[] command = this.cmd.PackSelector(msgbody, type);
        return !this.Send(state, command) ? "-4" : "0";
    }
```

this is from the documentation:

**4.3.6 Get reader power**

```
public string GetPower(AsynSocketState state);
Parameters:
state: Communication handle.
* return value:
Success returns "0", failure returns "-4"
Value:
    Loop:Open loop/closed loop "0" open loop "1" closed loop        result[3]   
readpower:Reader read power, return value "5~30"              result[4]
writepower:Write power of reader, return value "5~30"           result[5]
```

setting the power is quite straight forward and the max power according to the docs is 30 which I set and I get 0 in return which is returned on success.

The code to get power is also returning only a string and is also returning 0 but according to the docs there are more values in somewhere labeled as result[3] result[4] and so on.

What do these 'result' values mean how do I get those values

Comment: does AsyncSocketState object have some variables in the documentation? what string is the GetPower function call returning?

Comment: It seems to me like there is a ```Reader``` object with functions ```readpower()``` and ```writepower()```

Comment: essentially the last 2 lines for get reader power doc is telling us that readpower and writepower will return a string value between 5 and 30 units of power. the set and get power functions seem to be changing something within the AsynSocketState object which the docs refer to as the 'communication handle'. Perhaps we could get the reader instance from a method within AsynSocketState. In both functions we can see that ```msgbody``` is being passed to ```PackSelector``` which is making use of it in some way. perhaps the result[n] is referring to indices in the ```msgbody``` array

Comment: hey man I have been reassigned, thanks for your reply I will get back to you when I am done with my present work. Thanks again